# Can not figure out this multi step puzzle book problem (C++)?

Tags: c++

I am stuck on Step 6, and the program always returns a negative value.

Question:

1. Ask the user for a number (integer)
2. Add 3 to the number
3. Multiply the result of step 2 by the number 2
4. Subtract 4 from the result of step 3
5. Divide the result of step 4 by the number 2
6. Subtract the original number from step 1 from the result of step 5
7. Write out the result of step 6 to the user

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    y = x + 3;
    y = x * 2;
    y = x - 4;
    y = x / 2;
    y = y - x;
    cout << "The result is " << y << endl;

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: *"I am stuck on Step 6"* -- you might think that, but it appears to me that you have already failed at step 3.

Comment: step 2 is `y = x + 3;` step 3 is "Multiply the **result of step 2** by the number 2". What is the result of step 2?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you are still using the base value (the number from input) for next calculations and not the results from previous calculations.
Here is modified code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    y = x + 3;
    y = y * 2;
    y = y - 4;
    y = y / 2;
    y = y - x;
    cout << "The result is " << y << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want y=y-4

the result of step 4 is y, not x

Comment: i don't think that is the only place where the wrong variable is used

Answer (score 0):

```
  int main()

  {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;

       cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
       cin >> x; 
       y=((((x+3)*2)-4)/2);
       z=y-x;
   cout << "The result is " << z << endl;

   return 0;

 }
```

Comment: If you take that route, why not make it `y=((((x + 3) * 2) - 4) / 2) - x;`? Also, add some explanation to the answer why this works and why OP:s code doesn't.

Comment: You can work also like this.